# Does the NEC recommend metal or plastic boxes for 240V?

Tags: electrical, thermostat, 240v, junction-box

I need to install a junction box for 240V going to two separate Thermostats for baseboard heaters (one 750W and another 1100W). Should Does NEC require that I use plastic or metal boxes for the thermostats and junction box? I can't find anything in NEC that states a requirement.

Comment: So long as they meet code, it's your choice. Therefore, this is an opinion based question and off-topic.

Comment: Why use boxes at all?   *Oh, right.*  Okay, if we're using boxes *for actual reasons*, then **every single reason to use a box is better served by a metal box**. Plastic boxes are designed to install 10 seconds faster - which only benefits builders.

Answer (score 3):

Depends what your needs are.

From a practical standpoint, the purpose of a junction box is to contain any arcing that might occur. It doesn't matter if it's metal or plastic.

Metal's big advantage is to accommodate larger wires a bit more easily. You can readily buy boxes with a large knockout. The drawback is cost: you'll need a clamp for every knockout to properly hold the wire.

Plastic doesn't generally need a knockout, but a larger wire (in the US, 240v wire is 3-line cable, which means its larger) will have a harder time going into the box past the plastic barbs that are designed to hold the wire in place. You can buy plastic boxes without barbs, but you'll have to secure the wire within 8" or so of the box.

Answer (score 3):

The NEC doesn't care what material, so long as it's a listed and approved junction box, of an appropriate size for the number and gauge of wires and other items that count towards "box fill" (internal clamps, devices in the junction box, etc.)

I prefer steel for durability and better protection against faults, but that's an opinion, not code.

In Canada & USA 120 & 240 are very rarely treated any differently in code (both are 120V to ground/neutral, 240 is just two of those that are 240V from each other.)

Answer (score 2):

Metal can contain arcing much better than plastic. Plus if a hot wire gets loose and touches the box it is an immediate short and breaker trip, where in a plastic box it would be lurking, waiting to cause trouble...

Grounding is a big plus in metal boxes. Most switches and better quality receptacles will ground directly through the yoke to the box, where with a plastic box you have to connect a ground wire separately.